# How do I adjust the length of legend box in R?

Tags: r

Would you please recommend me the way to decrease the length of legend box in R? I am getting the extra unwanted space between different variables in the legend. I think I can remove those spaces by decreasing the size of the legend box.

Comment: Did you try changing cex? e.g. `cex=0.6`?

Comment: I tried that, my problem is not with cex, my problem is with the extra space between two different variables in the legend put horizontally. For eg : [a b    c               d] ; here in the example you can see some extra space between c and d.

Comment: please add a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You could use `y.intersp` and `x.intersp` to control the space between legend labels.

Comment: That decreases the length of the box ,,but still the space between two legends did't get less....

Comment: It brings the legend variables closer, but not the symbols.

Comment: Add `text.width`. For example `text.width=c(0.3,0.3)` if you have three lables.